# ggplot bar plot side by side using two variables

Tags: r

I want to create a barplot using ggplot in R studio using two variables side by side. I tried following other people suggestions I found online, but I cant get it to work.

Here's the data I'm using:

```
x <- c(5,17,31,9,17,10,30,28,16,29,14,34)

y <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)

day <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
```

So, what I'm trying to do is have days on the x-axis and side by side barplots of x and y (with x & y being colored) corresponding to the day number.

First thing i did was make a data frame :

```
df1 <- data.frame(x,y,day)
```

and then I tried:

> ggplot(df1, aes(x = day, y = x,y)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity",color = x, width = 1, position="dodge")

But I just can't get it to work properly. Any suggestions as to how I'd achieve this?

Comment: follow-up question: Did you want the color to be based on the day? or is the color based on whether they are in the "x" or "y" group?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You have the right idea, I think the `melt()` function from the `reshape2` package is what you're looking for.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

x <- c(5,17,31,9,17,10,30,28,16,29,14,34)
y <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
day <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)


df1 <- data.frame(x, y, day)
df2 <- melt(df1, id.vars='day')
head(df2)

ggplot(df2, aes(x=day, y=value, fill=variable)) +
    geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge')
```

[image]

**EDIT**
I think the `pivot_longer()` function from the tidyverse `tidyr` package might now be the better way to handle these types of data manipulations. It gives quite a bit more control than `melt()` and there's also a `pivot_wider()` function as well to do the opposite.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

x <- c(5,17,31,9,17,10,30,28,16,29,14,34)
y <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
day <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)


df1 <- data.frame(x, y, day)
df2 <- tidyr::pivot_longer(df1, cols=c('x', 'y'), names_to='variable', 
values_to="value")
head(df2)

ggplot(df2, aes(x=day, y=value, fill=variable)) +
    geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge')
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was going for... Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5):

Or you could use `facet_wrap` to produce two plots:

```
  library("ggplot2")
  library("reshape")
  x <- c(5,17,31,9,17,10,30,28,16,29,14,34)
  y <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
  day <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
  df1 <- data.frame(x,y,day)
  df2 <- reshape::melt(df1, id = c("day"))
  ggplot(data = df2, aes(x = day, y = value, fill = variable)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")+ facet_wrap(~ variable) + scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1,12,2))
```

[image]
If you want the bars with color according to the day use `fill = day`:

```
ggplot(data = df2, aes(x = day, y = value, fill = day)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") + facet_wrap(~ variable) + scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1,12,2))
```

[image]

Comment: Also worth noting that the days won't be on a continuous scale like this if you convert `day` to factor

Comment: you could use `+ scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1,12,2))` for integer values on the x-axis.