# Barplot with ggplot2 of element frequency in two databases

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I have a list of elements; here I chose letters "a, o, u, ü".
and their frequencies in two databases.

`df <- as.data.frame(cbind( letter = c("a", "o", "u", "ü"), 
             Freq.english = c("10", "50", "20", ""),
             Freq.german = c("10", "50", "10", "10") ))`

How can I display their frequencies in one graph with ggplot2?

I can display them separately and could also later join them:

`p.df1 <- ggplot(df,aes(x = letter ,y=Freq.english))+geom_bar(stat ="identity")`

`p.df2 <- ggplot(df,aes(x = letter ,y=Freq.german))+geom_bar(stat ="identity")`

However, it would be nice if they occur just next to each other, maybe
even separated by color. (smimilar to these solutions [ggplot bar plot side by side using two variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42820677/ggplot-bar-plot-side-by-side-using-two-variables))
THX

Update:

I managed to adapt the link to my data frame:

`df <- reshape::melt(df, id = c("letter"))
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = letter, y = value, fill = droplevels(variable)    )) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")+ facet_wrap(~ variable)`

Now, the value-axis does not start at 0, hence there is a bar at Freq.english at "ü", even though 0 occurences.

Also, I need to sort the values for both variables independently in ascending order.

THX

Comment: Did you try that solution? What result did it give? What kind of plot do you need?

Comment: @NelsonGon I now managed to change my data frame according to that solution; see the Update...thank you

Answer (score 1):

This would do I guess..

```
df %>% 
  gather(key = langauge, value = Freq, -letter) %>% 
  mutate(Freq = as.integer(Freq)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(letter, Freq, fill = langauge)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```