# How to label an histogram in R

Tags: r, statistics, histogram

I have something very similar to the first answer(the accepted one) to the problem in this link.

[ggplot bar plot side by side using two variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42820677/ggplot-bar-plot-side-by-side-using-two-variables)

How do I change it, so that instead of reading "variable" in the histogram I read any other word of chose, as well as "x" and "y"

Comment: @CalumYou At least part of it, trying to figure out the other (labeling "x" and "y")

Comment: Use the `labs()` command to change any labels. `[[your plot code]] + labs(fill = "fill legend title", x = "Label for x axis", y = "Label for y axis")`.